# HTTP parsing with authentication in Arduino + ethernet shield

Tags: arduino-uno, shields, ethernet, ethernet-shield

i am trying to parse a page from the route by using Arduino + Ethernet shield. before Arduino testing. I tested my code via python as it shows below. from this code i can get the data as i wish where we need authenticate user name and pass word to access to the router, as you see, here ( admin , admin) in the same time i have to used output variable to get only the data required. Python code is does it.

**Python code:**

```
My_url = "http://192.168.8.1/update.cgi"
r = requests.post (My_url, auth=('admin', 'admin'),data = 'output=netdev' )
print(r.status_code)
print(r.headers['content-type'])
print(r.encoding)
print(r.text)
```

**The output is:**

```
200
text/javascript
ISO-8859-1
netdev = {
 'WIRED':{rx:0x84154,tx:0x5a0cba}
,'BRIDGE':{rx:0x7e680,tx:0x59d98a}
,'WIRELESS0':{rx:0x0,tx:0x0}
,'WIRELESS1':{rx:0x0,tx:0x0}
}
```

Now i am trying to do that by using Arduino + Ethernet shield and i would like print the output on the serial port as it is showing below. Here the router is server and the Arduino is client.

**My problem** is the POST request with the authentication, How I can do it ( POST with authentication + 'output=netdev' like in python code ). Please any idea .. Many thanks in advanced

**Arduino code :**

```
#include <Ethernet.h>
#include <SPI.h>

// Enter a MAC address for your controller below.
// Newer Ethernet shields have a MAC address printed on a sticker on the shield
byte mac[] = { 0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xED };

// if you don't want to use DNS (and reduce your sketch size)
// use the numeric IP instead of the name for the server:
IPAddress server(192,168,8,1);  // numeric IP for Google (no DNS)
//char server[] = "jsonplaceholder.typicode.com";    // name address for Google (using DNS)

// Set the static IP address to use if the DHCP fails to assign
IPAddress ip(192, 168, 8, 100);
IPAddress myDns(   8, 8, 8, 8);

// Initialize the Ethernet client library
// with the IP address and port of the server
// that you want to connect to (port 80 is default for HTTP):
EthernetClient client;

void setup()
{
  // Open serial communications and wait for port to open:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial) {
    ; // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for native USB port only
  }

  // start the Ethernet connection:
  Serial.println("Initialize Ethernet with DHCP:");
  if (Ethernet.begin(mac) == 0) {
    Serial.println("Failed to configure Ethernet using DHCP");
    // Check for Ethernet hardware present
    if (Ethernet.hardwareStatus() == EthernetNoHardware) {
      Serial.println("Ethernet shield was not found.  Sorry, can't run without hardware. :(");
      while (true) {
        delay(1); // do nothing, no point running without Ethernet hardware
      }
    }
    if (Ethernet.linkStatus() == LinkOFF) {
      Serial.println("Ethernet cable is not connected.");
    }
    // try to congifure using IP address instead of DHCP:
    Ethernet.begin(mac, ip, myDns);
  } else {
    Serial.print("  DHCP assigned IP ");
    Serial.println(Ethernet.localIP());
  }
  delay(1000);
  Serial.println("connecting...");

  if (client.connect(server, 80)) {
    Serial.print("connected to ");
    Serial.println(client.remoteIP());
    // Make a HTTP request:

    client.println("POST /update.cgi HTTP/1.0");
    client.println("Host: 192.168.8.1");
    client.println("Connection: close");
    client.println();
  } else {
    Serial.println("connection failed");
  }
}

void loop()
{
  //if (client.available()) {
  while (client.available()) {
    char c = client.read();
    Serial.print(c);

  }

  if (!client.connected()) {
    Serial.println();
    Serial.println("disconnecting.");
    client.stop();
    for(;;)
      ;
  }

}
```

**Arduino output**

```
Initialize Ethernet with DHCP:
  DHCP assigned IP 192.168.8.107
connecting...
connected to 192.168.8.1
HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized
Server: httpd
Date: Sat, 01 Jan 2011 00:27:00 GMT
WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="DR3800"
Content-Type: text/html
Connection: close

<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>401 Unauthorized</TITLE></HEAD>
<BODY BGCOLOR="#cc9999"><H4>401 Unauthorized</H4>
Authorization required.
</BODY></HTML>

disconnecting.
```

---

Thank you Dougie for your anser. I used it , please you can see it in my code below where i used this library it gives no error for GET request , but when i use it ti POST request it gives same authentication problem as you see . where the POST request is important to get the data from .cgi page . Maybe i use that in wrong way .. any advice ? thanks

```
void loop() {
  Serial.println("making GET request with HTTP basic authentication");
  String contentType = "update.cgi";
  String postData = "output=netdev";

  client.beginRequest();
  client.get("/"+contentType);
  client.sendBasicAuth("admin", "admin"); // send the username and password for authentication
  client.endRequest();

   // read the status code and body of the response
  int statusCode = client.responseStatusCode();
  String response = client.responseBody();

  Serial.print("Status code: ");
  Serial.println(statusCode);
  Serial.print("Response: ");
  Serial.println(response);

  Serial.println("Wait five seconds");
  delay(5000);
}
```

### The output is ok

```
making GET request with HTTP basic authentication
Status code: 200
Response: 
Wait five seconds
```

### But for POST as follows :

```
void loop() {
  Serial.println("making GET request with HTTP basic authentication");
  String contentType = "update.cgi";
  String postData = "output=netdev";

  client.beginRequest();
  client.post("/",contentType , postData);
  client.sendBasicAuth("admin", "admin"); // send the username and password for authentication
  client.endRequest();

   // read the status code and body of the response
  int statusCode = client.responseStatusCode();
  String response = client.responseBody();

  Serial.print("Status code: ");
  Serial.println(statusCode);
  Serial.print("Response: ");
  Serial.println(response);

  Serial.println("Wait five seconds");
  delay(5000);
}
```

### the output is :

```
making GET request with HTTP basic authentication
Status code: 401
Response: <HTML><HEAD><TITLE>401 Unauthorized</TITLE></HEAD>
<BODY BGCOLOR="#cc9999"><H4>401 Unauthorized</H4>
Authorization required.
</BODY></HTML>

Wait five seconds
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than trying to send your own GET/POST request by hand coding it, use https://github.com/arduino-libraries/ArduinoHttpClient which does it all for you.

Comment: Use the `sendBasicAuth` method to send auth. data.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I used it , please you can see it in my code [    String contentType = "update.cgi";
String postData = "output=netdev";
client.beginRequest();
  client.post("/",contentType , postData);
  client.sendBasicAuth("admin", "admin"); // send the username and password for authentication
  client.endRequest(); ] and stil i have problem with POST methode. any idea

Comment: Please vote up my answer and mark it as accepted.